# retrieving html formatted content with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I will like to know if it is first of GOOD IDEA and secondly SAFE to pass html formatted data from an external server to a jquerymobile phonegap app

example, i make a request from phonegap app to a server and it return data formatted like the one below.

```
<ul> 
    <li> David Addoteye <p>Age: 30years</p>
    <p>Location: ghana</p> <p>Accra Ghana</p> 
     <img src="icons/status-up.png"> 
    </li>
    <li> Samuel Anim <p>Age: 20years</p>
    <p>Location: USA</p> <p>New York</p> 
    <img src="icons/status-up.png">  </li>  
     <li> Grace Better <p>Age: 30years</p>
     <p>Location: UK</p> <p>London</p>
      <img src="icons/status-up.png"> </li>
</ul>
```

Thank you

Comment: Is html data is coming from middle-tier layer or database?

Comment: i think for data transferring you should use `XML` or `JSON` instead of `HTML`

Comment: @Unknown i am using php to pull a raw data from mysql database and then format it with html before passing it to the app

Answer (score 4):

Speaking of **Safety**, Data could be intercepted regardless of formatting - so formatting or plain text doesn't really matter. I have used XML formatted data for various applications. 
(But, if you are looking for a more specific answer, in your case, more info is probably required to determine the *safety* and *best practices* of your usage)

Comment: thanks, the app is a casual location search app with no sensitive data request. i want to know whether it is possible to do that, that is passing an html data from external server to a phonegap app and secondly whether it is a good idea

Comment: If you are utilising the data to display it on your front-end anyway (i.e. not some data the user cant see), then, for ease of use, I would just use the response xml, as you have shown.